# In JSF HttpServletRequest object getAttribute() returning Null

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have Two different JSF page Let Us suppose **A.jsf** and **B.jsf** But Both calling same managed bean different methods `ManagedBean.java`

**A.jsf** is calling a SessionScoped Managed bean method where i set some attribute in Request class object

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
request.setAttribute("token", requestToken.getToken()); 
        request.setAttribute("tokenSecret", requestToken.getTokenSecret());
```

Then redirecting some other side like this

```
response.sendRedirect(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());
```

Now after successful login i am opening another JSF page of my website suppose **b.jsf** and from this page i am calling method like this

```
<f:event listener="#{ManagedBean.redirectLogin2}" type="preRenderView" />
```

and calling same Managedbean but another method

```
public String redirectLogin2() throws TwitterException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
}
```

But when i am doing in above method `redirectLogin2()`

```
request.getAttribute("token")
request.getAttribute("tokenSecret")
```

Both giving Null. What cab be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Request scoped attribute life span will be lost on `sendRedirect`. You should set value on session scope.

```
 HttpSession session=request.getSession();
 session.setAttribute("token", requestToken.getToken()); 
 session.setAttribute("tokenSecret", requestToken.getTokenSecret());
```

After setting value to session. You can access that from request like

```
 HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext
            .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

request.getSession().getAttribute("token");
request.getSession().getAttribute("tokenSecret");
```

Although, above code will work but that is not good practice. JSF has `@SessionScoped` annotation which will make available of your variable access with login session.

Comment: Same issue no any success with above code as well even i tried 

'ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
  Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();
  String yourVariable = (String) sessionMap.get("token");'

Comment: Still i did not get any help